# How to change specific value inside multiple datatables in dataset using C# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I have multiple datatables inside dataset bound to database, I want to update the value of specific row inside the datable.

Let suppose I have 2 datatables with values:

```
     a
     ab
     abc
     abcd

     x
     xy
     xyz
```

All I want is to update the 'xy' and 'abc' values to xy_default and abc_defaut.

Thanks.

Comment: this is pretty simple to do with datatables however you need to display a little bit of effort this is not a code factory site. do a google search and you will find tons of working examples.. are you familiar with looping through records in a DataTable.. are you familiar with the .Contains Method as well as the Replace method..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to above two comment , I am just giving you pointer make use of **linq to dataset** and start getting information about it so you could not have to ask question for easy things

```
datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row["value"].ToString()=="xy")
    .ToList().ForEach(row => row["Collected"] = "xy_default");


public void UpdateRow(datatable,value)
{
     datatable.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row["value"].ToString()==value)
        .ToList().ForEach(row => row["Collected"] = value + "_default");
}
```

Note : this just example assuming that you are having value in table i.e no null value in the row.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, your code is working fine but I have multiple tables inside dataset and I can't pass the specific value to check and then update it.

Comment: @naeemmalik - as i told you it pointer ..you can create generic function for your need and do changes accordingly..